# A question on Arithmetic Progressions is given in the picture below..

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, polynomials

What is the sum of an arithmetic progression whose first term is $a$, the second term is $b$, and the last term is $c$?

A. $\dfrac{(b+c-2a)(a+c)}{2(b-a)}$

B. $\dfrac{(b+c+a)(a+c)}{2b-a}$

C. $\dfrac{2(a+c)(b-c+2a)}{b+a}$

D. $\dfrac{(b+c-2a)(a-c)}{b+a}$

Comment: Could you please *type* the question? And be it for the benefit of the readers to come

Comment: I just dont know how Is there a Equation Inserter or something here???

Comment: Thanks @clarinetist for typing it out...THanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

So, the common difference is $b-a$

If the $c$ is the $n$ the term $c=a+(n-1)(b-a),$ find $n$ in terms of $a,b,c$

Now, use the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Derivation) of summation of an Arithmetic Series

Comment: You won by 4 seconds ! Cheers.

Comment: So you mean in the formula for sum of an arithmetic progression, I have to replace 'n' by 'c' ????

Comment: @Sudhanshu, do you recognize $c=a+(n−1)(b−a)$ as a linear equation in $n,$ the unknown variable I've introduced?

Comment: So I should re-arrange the equation to get n and then substitute it in the  formula for sum of an arithmetic progression

Comment: @Sudhanshu, yes, we already know the sum to be $$\frac n2\cdot(a+c)$$

Comment: I solved and did as you said so is the ANSWER = A ...???

Comment: @Sudhanshu, nice to hear your first statement. Not sure whether I should answer your query or not?

Comment: Here is how I solved IT......http://i.stack.imgur.com/2BITC.jpg

Comment: @Sudhanshu, correct your method is

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* In the exceptional case where $a=b=c\ne 0$, it is impossible to determine the number of summands, so the correct formula must fail. The only expression that indeed fails in this way is the first.

Answer (score 0):

[image: A]

The answer I got after solving from steps and guided by @lab bhattacharjee